# Python CSV: Append to COLUMN, duplicate entries

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to write to a CSV file, every new entry to a column, but every time the CSV file gets duplicate entries. I'd want to create the 1, 2, 3 rows only if they do not exist, to be the first, and then add data to column 1, 2 and 3.
I am having the current code:

```
import _csv

myData = [[1, 2, 3], ['Good Morning', 'Good Evening', 'Good Afternoon']]
myFile = open('csvexample3.csv', 'a')
with myFile:
   writer = _csv.writer(myFile)
   writer.writerows(myData)
```

And the result I get:

```
1,2,3
Good Morning,Good Evening,Good Afternoon
1,2,3
Good Morning,Good Evening,Good Afternoon
1,2,3
Good Morning,Good Evening,Good Afternoon
```

I'd only like the script to create the 1, 2 and 3 columns if they **DO NOT** exist, else I'd like to append the file to that rows. This script will be a function, so it needs to check if the columns exist and append to them.

Comment: Please edit the question to also show the output that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code. Explanation are added as comments:

```
myData = [[1, 2, 3], ['Good Morning', 'Good Evening', 'Good Afternoon']]

# CREATE DATA FIRST AND THEN ADD IT TO FILE: 
dd = []     # an empty list to be filled with values to be added
dd.append(",".join(list(map(lambda x: str(x), myData[0])))) # add column header
for i in range(3):
    dd.append(",".join(myData[1]))          # add rows

# CHECK IF FILE EXIST AND THEN TAKE ACTION: 
import os
if os.path.exists("calling.txt"):   
    with open("calling.txt", 'a') as ff:    # create existing file for appending
        for i in dd[1:]:                    # omit adding header
            ff.write(i)
            ff.write("\n")
else: 
    with open("calling.txt", 'w') as ff:    # create new file for writing
        for i in dd:                        # add rows including header
            ff.write(i)
            ff.write("\n")
```